# Export function in c++ static library

Tags: c++, export, static-libraries

My app links to a third party static library which without source code and I find that a function implemented in this library is exported in my exe using dumpbin.exe, just like a export function in a DLL. 
I have tried to modify the header file provided by the library, got rid of all the __declspec(dllexport) stuffs, and relink my app, but the function is still exported.
Does it have a way to make it unexported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will have to recompile the library itself, changing the header will not affect the library binary code. What problems is the exported function causing you?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: It generates a MyApp.lib file and a MyApp.exp file that seems a little confusing.